# R: How to have an askme popup inside an rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to configure a widget which requires credentials. I set up the following ifelse() statement which checks if the user has saved credentials and if not prompts a popup box for input.

```r
library(Rnssp)
ifelse(file.exists("~/mytest.rda"),load("~/mytest.rda"),myProfile <- Credentials$new(
  username = askme("Enter yourESSENCE username: "),
  password = askme()))
```

It seems to work on it's own, but not when I try to include it within the rmarkdown script. If the credentials are already saved, it works, but if they're not I get
"Error: string is not a string (a length of one vector)."

I'd like it to stop the code in-line, since it's needed later in the script, but as I'm writing this I'm realizing this may need something aside from rmarkdown. Any suggestions on how I might implement this?

Comment: You're using `ifelse` wrong, **use `if`**. Why is it wrong? First, _never_ do `<-` assignment within ifelse, it often does not do what one needs/expects; second, ifelse has complications/liabilities (e.g., not class-safe); third, ifelse should return _simple objects_ like numeric, character, logical, it should generally not be used on arbitrary structures; fourth, the `yes=` and `no=` arguments should always be the same class, where in this case `yes=` returns `character` and `no=` returns some type of complex object (S4/R6/??).

Comment: The notion of Rmarkdown documents (unless they are really "apps" using `shiny`) is that they are rendered in isolation without user interaction. If you need the rmarkdown document to have credentials to do _something_ (e.g., database credentials, API key), then you should pass those credentials as [parameters](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html). One step further, though, I find it is _much safer_ to not require the Rmd document to actually query anything, passing all data (via `params:`); there are clearly several easy exceptions to this recommendation.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the feedback! I was unaware of the differences between if and ifelse but I'll take some time to look into that. For the credentials, I'll look into parameters. I do have one question about that RE API calls: so I'm trying to set this up to automatically modify the API string to update the dates of the data pulled to the most recent data. can parameters take arguments like Paste0() and Sys.Date()?

Comment: Parameters are to rmarkdown documents as arguments are to functions, treat them as such. For instance, if you do something like `rmarkdown::render("path/to/file.Rmd", params=list(cred=mycreds, when=Sys.Date()))`, then inside your Rmd file it would have available `params$cred` and `params$when`. The link I provided in my second comment has many really good examples of using them.